# How to define key in this code python

Tags: python

I want my code to record the latest 3 scores for each student and when a 4th one is added it will overwrite the oldest score and replace it with the new one. I need the layout to be:

```
f,7,8,9
```

I have created this code but when i run it it asks me to define key. This is my code:

```
pname = input("What is your name")
correct = input("What is your score")
SCORE_FILENAME  = "Class1.txt"
MAX_SCORES = 3

try: scoresFile = open('Class1.txt', "r+")
except IOError: scoresFile = open('Class1.txt', "w+") # File not exists

actualScoresTable = dict()

for line in scoresFile:
    tmp = line.replace("\n","").split(",")
    actualScoresTable[tmp[0]]=tmp[1:]
scoresFile.close()


if pname not in actualScoresTable.keys():
    actualScoresTable[pname] = [correct]
else:
    actualScoresTable[pname].append(correct)
    if MAX_SCORES < len(actualScoresTable[pname]):
            actualScoresTable[key].pop(0)


scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "w+") # Truncating file (write all again)
for key in actualScoresTable.keys():
    scoresFile.write("%s,%s\n" % (key, ','.join(actualScoresTable[key])))
scoresFile.close()
```

When i run the code it tells me that 'key' is not defined.
How would i define key?
I have been told that it needs to be a tuple but i dont know  how to make it that and for my code to work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Milan\Documents\Python\Task 3 tries\3 scores.py", line 23, in <module>
    actualScoresTable[key].pop(0)
NameError: name 'key' is not defined
```

Comment: 1. your code is not indented properly. 2. what is the exact error you're getting (post it with the stacktrace). Which line causes the error?

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong code

Comment: @alfasin this is the error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Milan\Documents\Python\Task 3 tries\3 scores.py", line 23, in <module>
    actualScoresTable[key].pop(0)
NameError: name 'key' is not defined

Comment: Well, it isn't defined. Did you perhaps mean `pname` instead of `key` there?

Comment: It's a dictionary, not a list. If you `pop()` from a dictionary you should use a key that exists there. The key `0` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error is in this line:

`actualScoresTable[key].pop(0)`

You don't define key until after this code. 
I think what you want is `actualScoresTable[pname].pop(0)`.